# what is the difference between padding and margin?

Tags: stylesheet

what is the difference between padding and margin?

both do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

This image is the better explanation

Answer (score 3):

Wrong!

Padding is internal padding for items inside elements.

Margin is the external padding for the positioning of said element.

[edit] link for goodness: http://webdesign.about.com/od/faqsandhelp/f/bl_faq5_7a.htm

Answer (score 3):

- **Padding** defines the space between the border and the content.
- **Margin** defines the space between other outside elements and the broder.

[image: from xhtml.com]
<sub>(source: [xhtml.com](http://xhtml.com/C12742E4-3FD2-4084-9E7F-833805A4157C/box-model.gif))</sub>

Of course if you don't specify a border, it looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

Margin is distance **outside** the container's border. Padding is the distance **inside** of it.

Check out the box model for CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

Padding adds space between the margins of the control and the *inner content*.

Margins adds space between the margisn of the control and the *outer container*.